# Are there some tables or handbooks of homology and homotopy groups of every manifold which has been calculated?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, textbook-recommendation

Are there some tables or handbooks of homology and homotopy groups of every manifold which has been calculated? Or are there some tables or handbooks which list some common calculated results of  differential geometry, differential topology and algebraic topology?

Comment: Most likely not. Why would one need such a table? And what is "every manifold"?

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev I mean some common manifolds, such as SU(n), SO(n), RP^n and so on. Not every textbook of algebraic topology will calculate these all. If I will use some of them, I have to calculate them. Are there something like table of integrals which I can only consult when I need them.

Comment: Just don't use lousy textbooks. In my opinion, the ultimate textbook is Fomenko, Fuchs, "A course in homotopy topology". It contains all groups one can imagine! Alas, it's in Russian; I'm surprised that no one has translated it yet.

Comment: http://www.math.columbia.edu/~khovanov/gradat2014/FFG1.pdf

Comment: I am very fond of Fomenko-Fuchs's book, but this is an introductory text and not a replacement for say Toda's book on homotopy groups of spheres.

Comment: Here are quite a few examples: https://neil-strickland.staff.shef.ac.uk/courses/bestiary/bestiary.pdf

Comment: It's a mystery that a dominant reference of this kind, a sort of 'Gradshteyn-Ryzhik of algebraic topology' has not appeared. A difference in mindset between the consumers of topological information and information about special functions perhaps?

Answer (score 13):

Matthias Kreck and collaborators have set out to create an encyclopaedic catalog of manifolds and their properties a while ago (http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Main_Page), although I don't think it's quite at a stage where one might describe it as useful. Its aim is to collect all known information about "real-world" manifolds, whatever that means. It's a wiki, so if you're interested in helping assemble such a catalog, you might consider contributing.
Personally I think that the world of manifolds is too rich and, well, manifold, to be usefully catalogued in this way, but I'd love to be corrected.

Answer (score 9):

Such tables indeed exist even though only partial information is available, of course. Higher homotopy groups of $RP^n$ are the same as those of spheres, so look at tables  [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres). For Lie groups there is a good survey of Mimura ["Homotopy theory of Lie groups". Handbook of algebraic topology, 1995] with some tables if memory serves. There are also tables for exceptional Lie groups. If you want a more basic info there is a monograph "Topology of Lie groups I, II" by Mimura and Toda.

In general, I recommend a mathscinet search on "homotopy" and "Lie group" in the title. A number of things has happened since the above-mentioned works, and other information is in paper (not table) form. See e.g. [here](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.hha/1139839936).

Comment: Mimura's book also contains cohomology groups of homogeneous spaces.